# Magento: conditional free shipping

Tags: magento

I am trying to set conditional free shipping in our store.

The conditions are:
- if the cart subtotal is over $80, and
- there are no products from category A and subcategory A-a (Category is Hats, sub category is Akubra)

Here's how it looks:
Image 1: [http://imgur.com/lxhEA1f][1]
Image 2: [http://i.imgur.com/z2SbKKt.png][2]

(Sorry I didn't have enough reputation to post images.)

Anyway, I cannot get this to trigger.

If I add the exclude items to the basket (i.e. if I have one of those hats in the basket), then my flat rate shipping is still 0. If I remove products to get under the $80, I still see a $0 for flat rate shipping.

My Aus Post shipping still appears with non-zero values.

I have Magento's free shipping function turned off altogether.

I would appreciate any advice in getting this working!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

just mention your category id inside the action because condition workout cart basis and action work with item level basis.